# R: how to call feols regression within a function

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to write a function to return regression coefficient and standard errors since I need run a large number of regressions.
The data could look like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fixest)
library(broom)
data<-tibble(Date = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01"),
         Card = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
         A = rnorm(8),
         B = rnorm(8),
         C = rnorm(8)
         )
```

My current code is as following

```
estimation_fun <- function(col1,col2,df) {

  regression<-feols(df[[col1]] ~ df[[col2]] | Card + Date, df)

  est =tidy(regression)$estimate
  se = tidy(regression)$std.error

  output <- list(est,se)
  return(output)

}
estimation_fun("A","B",example)
```

However, it does not work. I guess it is related to column name in feols because I can make it work for `lm()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feols` function needs a formula object. You can create it using `paste0`/`sprintf`.

```
estimation_fun <- function(col1,col2,df) {
  
  regression<-feols(as.formula(sprintf('%s ~ %s | Card + Date', col1, col2)), df)
  
  est =tidy(regression)$estimate
  se = tidy(regression)$std.error
  
  output <- list(est,se)
  return(output)
  
}

estimation_fun("A","B",data)

#[[1]]
#[1] -0.1173276
#attr(,"type")
#[1] "Clustered (Card)"

#[[2]]
#[1] 1.083011
#attr(,"type")
#[1] "Clustered (Card)"
```

---

To apply this for every pair of variables you may do -

```
cols <- names(data)[-(1:2)]

do.call(rbind, combn(cols, 2, function(x) {
  data.frame(cols = paste0(x, collapse = '-'), 
             t(estimation_fun(x[1],x[2],data)))
}, simplify = FALSE))

   cols         X1        X2
#1  A-B -0.1173276  1.083011
#2  A-C -0.1117691 0.5648162
#3  B-C -0.3771884 0.1656587
```

Comment: thank you very much! Could you please show me how to apply this function over all the pairs of columns just as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511160/r-expand-grid-of-all-possible-combinations-within-groups-and-apply-functions-ac , except now I don't need 'date' in front of the output since I don't need group_split(Date).

Comment: Updated the answer to apply the function for every combination.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please make it 'tidyverse' style? Would like to make code consistent.

Comment: and ideally, I would need all the pairs (i.e., A-B, B-A are different in this setting)

Comment: Something like your answer in last question: tmp <- expand.grid(firm1 = names(data[-1]), firm2 = names(data[-1]))
result <- data %>%
  group_split(time) %>%
  map_df(~cbind(time = .x$time[1], tmp, 
                value = apply(tmp, 1, function(x) fun(.x[[x[1]]], .x[[x[2]]]))))

Comment: NVM, Ronak, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Ronak's right: only formulas made of variable names can be used.

Since `fixest` 0.10.0, you can use the dot square bracket operator to do just that. See the help page for formula manipulation in [xpd](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/reference/xpd.html#examples).

Just change one line in your code to make it work:

```
estimation_fun <- function(lhs, rhs, df) {
  # lhs must be of length 1 (otherwise => not what you'd want)
  # rhs can be a vector of variables
  regression <- feols(.[lhs] ~ .[rhs] | Card + Date, df)
  
  # etc...
}
```

```
# Example of how ".[]" works: 

lhs = "A"
rhs = c("B", "C")
feols(.[lhs] ~ .[rhs], data)
#> OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: A
#> Observations: 8 
#> Standard-errors: IID 
#>              Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|) 
#> (Intercept)  0.375548   0.428293  0.876849  0.42069 
#> B           -0.670476   0.394592 -1.699164  0.15004 
#> C            0.177647   0.537452  0.330536  0.75440 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> RMSE: 0.737925   Adj. R2: 0.183702
```

By the way, I recommend to use the built-in multiple estimation facility (see help [here](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/multiple_estimations.html)) since estimation speed will be substantially improved.

### Update

All combinations can be estimated with one line of code:

```
# All combinations at once
est_all = feols(c(A, B, C) ~ sw(A, B, C) | Card + Date, data)
```

Extraction of coefs/SEs can be done with another line:

```
# Coef + SE // see doc for summary.fixest_multi
coef_se_all = summary(est_all, type = "se_long")
coef_se_all
#>    lhs rhs type          A          B          C
#> 1    A   A coef  1.0000000         NA         NA
#> 2    A   A   se        NaN         NA         NA
#> 3    A   B coef         NA  0.8204932         NA
#> 4    A   B   se         NA  1.1102853         NA
#> 5    A   C coef         NA         NA -0.7889534
#> 6    A   C   se         NA         NA  0.3260451
#> 7    B   A coef  0.2456443         NA         NA
#> 8    B   A   se  0.2314143         NA         NA
#> 9    B   B coef         NA  1.0000000         NA
#> 10   B   B   se         NA        NaN         NA
#> 11   B   C coef         NA         NA -0.1977089
#> 12   B   C   se         NA         NA  0.3335988
#> 13   C   A coef -0.4696954         NA         NA
#> 14   C   A   se  0.3858851         NA         NA
#> 15   C   B coef         NA -0.3931512         NA
#> 16   C   B   se         NA  0.8584968         NA
#> 17   C   C coef         NA         NA  1.0000000
#> 18   C   C   se         NA         NA        NaN
```

NOTA: it requires `fixest` 0.10.1 or higher.

Comment: Thanks. My setting requires all pairs of variables like A~B, A~C, B~A, B~C, C~A,C~B, etc., and then extract coefficients and standard errors. Do you have suggestions of doing this?

Comment: Thanks again. Could you please make est_all more reproducible since the number of columns (A, B, C, ...) is really large in my data. Maybe something like cols <- names(data[-1]) ~ sw(names(data[-1]))?

Comment: BTW, is fixest 0.10.1 develop version?

Comment: 0.10.1 is indeed the development version. And Nick, please, don't you think you're abusing our time? Both replies are answers to your original question. You may think to hiring someone.

Comment: OK. Sorry. And thanks anyway!